# OpenTBS - Content from MySQL as HTML

Tags: php, cakephp, opentbs

I have setup OpenTBS to generate dynamically from my contacts database. Now I want to setup the actual content of the email to come from a MySQL table created using CKeditor or another WYSISYG JS editor.

I have been able to get the content to display on the outputted docx file but it is coming this as a straing with the html tags, I somehow need this to format so it comes though as it was put in by the client. I am only going to allow them to use the basics, paragrahs, bold, italics and maybe a few other tags.

Is this someway I can convert this html string to word copy / text? Or somehow have a different WYSIWYG editor to save it in MySQL as word code rather then html code.

Thanks

It's not really relevant but below is the function that generates the OpenTBS document from a template and the database (I am using CakePHP)    MailMerge.description is the body with the html code at the moment.

```
// FUNCTION EXPORT MAIL MERGE
// -------------------------------------------------------------->
function mail_merge()
{
     Configure::write('debug',2);

    $this->layout = null;
    $this->autoRender = FALSE;  


    // GET THE CONTACTS
    // ------------------------------------------------------------->
    $contacts = $this->Contact->find('all', array('limit' => 20,  'contain' => FALSE));

    $this->loadModel('MailMerge');
    $content = $this->MailMerge->find('first', array(
                                                'conditions' => array('MailMerge.id' => 1),
                                                'fields' => array('MailMerge.description')
                                                ));


    // Get a new instance of TBS with the OpenTBS plug-in
    // ------------------------------------------------------------->
     $otbs = $this->Tbs->getOpenTbs(); 

    // Load the template file
    // ------------------------------------------------------------->
    $otbs->LoadTemplate(APP . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . '/files/data_files/enquiry_letter_sample_redcliffe.docx');

    // Merge data in the template
    // ------------------------------------------------------------->
    $otbs->MergeBlock('r', $contacts);
    $otbs->MergeBlock('content', $content);

    // End the merge and export
    // ------------------------------------------------------------->
    $file_name = 'export.docx';
    $otbs->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, $file_name);

}
```